# text is getting repeated though the template is unique

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below piece of XML.

```
<section level="sect2" number-type="manual">
    <para align="center">
                <phrase>24-2</phrase>
                <content-style font-style="italic">Destroying [or Damaging] property, contrary to section 60(1) of the Crimes Ordinance Cap 200, Laws of Hong Kong.</content-style>
            </para>
</section>
```

and when i apply the below XSLT

```
<xsl:template name="para" match="section/para">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current()/@align=center and ./@differentiation">
                <div class="para align-{@align}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </div>
            </xsl:when>
                   <xsl:when test="current()/@align=center and not(./@differentiation)">
                <div class="para align1-{@align}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </div>
            </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="current()/@align and ./phrase[1]">
                <div class="para new">
                     <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </div>
            </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="current()/@align">
                <div class="para align-{@align}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </div>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <div class="para">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </div>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="text()">

 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(([Cc]hapter)\s(\d+))">
      <xsl:matching-substring>


      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:variable name="num">
          <xsl:value-of select="string-length(regex-group(2))"/>
          </xsl:variable>

            <a
              href="{concat('er:#ABHK_CH_',format-number(number(regex-group(2)),'00'),'/P',format-number(number(regex-group(2)),'0'),'-',regex-group(3))}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </a>          





          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>



</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="phrase" match="phrase">
    <xsl:variable name="phrl">
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length(text())"/>
    </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="phrase">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('P',text())"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="newphrase" select="translate($phrase,'.','-')"/>
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="$newphrase">
                </xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </a>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="../@align">
              <span class="phrase">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
        </span>
            <span class="align-center">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
            </span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$phrl=3">
                  <span class="phrase">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
        </span>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#160;&amp;#160;&amp;#160;&amp;#160;&amp;#160;&amp;#160;&amp;#160;&amp;#160;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$phrl=4">
                  <span class="phrase">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
        </span>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#160;&amp;#160;&amp;#160;&amp;#160;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
        <span class="phrase">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
        </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>


    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="content-style">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./@format">
        <span class="{concat('format-',@format)}">
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:variable name="fontStyle">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-style-',@font-style)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <span class="{$fontStyle}">
        <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="../@align">
                                         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>

        </span>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>    
    </xsl:template>
```

the output i get is

```
24-2 Destroying [or Damaging] property, contrary to section 60(1) of the Crimes Ordinance Cap 200, Laws of Hong Kong. Destroying [or Damaging] property, contrary to section 60(1) of the Crimes Ordinance Cap 200, Laws of Hong Kong.
```

here `Destroying [or Damaging] property, contrary to section 60(1) of the Crimes Ordinance Cap 200, Laws of Hong Kong.` 
is getting repeated though the template is called once. please let me know where am i going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the template that matches the **para** element you are doing this

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

This will look at both the child nodes of the **para** element and select templates that match them. As one of the child elements is **content-style** this will obviously apply the template that matches it.

However, within the template that matches **phrase** (which is the other child of **para** you do this (in the case where the **para** element has an **align** attribute, which is does here)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
```

The following sibling is the **content-style**, and so this will also use the template. Thus the template matching **content-style** gets called twice.

One solution is to the template matching **para** so that instead of doing `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, it explicitly ignores nodes that following **phrase** elements

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='phrase'])]" />
```

Try this template for **para** instead

```
<xsl:template name="para" match="section/para">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current()/@align=center and ./@differentiation">
            <div class="para align-{@align}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='phrase'])]" />
            </div>
        </xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="current()/@align=center and not(./@differentiation)">
            <div class="para align1-{@align}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='phrase'])]" />
            </div>
        </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="current()/@align and ./phrase[1]">
            <div class="para new">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='phrase'])]" />
            </div>
        </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="current()/@align">
            <div class="para align-{@align}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='phrase'])]" />
            </div>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi @TimC thanks for solution, this is working good, but the content-style template is not getting called

Comment: Try changing `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>` as the former may pick up white-space text nodes.